# tomcat logging stdout stderr

Tags: tomcat

I start tomcat using the startup command in bin. How can I log to println to stdout and error to stderr instead of console? Which is the file to modify and how to modify? am using windows server 2008.

Answer (score 9):

If you run `bin/startup.bat`, then Tomcat should launch in the background and stdout/stderr should be redirected to `logs/catalina.out`. If, instead, you run `bin/catalina.sh run` (note the additional command-line argument "run"), then Tomcat should run in the console and all stdout/stderr should be displayed there.

Comment: am getting run is not recognised as a internal / external command

Comment: The command to run is `bin/catalina.bat` and `run` is a command-line argument to that script.

Comment: catalina.bat run caused app to run in consolbe but still printed to console

Comment: `bin\catalina.bat run` is designed to log stdout to the console (that is, no output redirection is performed). If you run `bin\catalina.bat start` (which is what `bin\startup.bat` does), then Tomcat should run in the background and redirect stdout to `logs\catalina.out`. If that's not happening, someone has broken your installation.